# How i can make this type of bottom tab bar styling

Tags: react-native

[Bottom tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LeWu.png)

//I have made basic styling like border and all but I need the curveness when i tap on the icons

Answer (score 0):

Is this link solution for you ?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

Also, you can find other navigation for react-native f.eg on github.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.